# Implement generic protocol method with but use generic for whole class

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, swift5

I'm am trying to implement a protocol method that has a generic argument, but then use the generic type for my entire class instead of just on the method, something like this

```
protocol FirstProtocol {
}

protocol SecondProtocol {
    func foo<T: FirstProtocol>(argument: T)
}

class MyType<T: FirstProtocol>: SecondProtocol {
    var value: T? = nil
    func foo<T>(argument: T) {
        value = argument     // ERROR: Cannot assign value of type 'T' to type 'T?'
    }
}
```

So the swift compiler accepts that `foo<T>(argument:T)` matches the method of `SecondProtocol`, if I comment out the error line it compiles fine, but it will not let me assign *argument* to *value* even though *value* and *argument* should be the same type, the compiler complains as if they are different types.

Comment: I tried `value = T?.some(argument)` and it gives me `Cannot assign value of type 'Optional<T>' to type 'T?'` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `argument` and `value` are indeed different types. The `T` generic parameter in `foo` is just an identifier, and I can change it to anything else:

```
class MyType<T: FirstProtocol>: SecondProtocol {
    var value: T? = nil
    func foo<AnythingElse>(argument: AnythingElse) {
        // MyType still conforms to SecondProtocol
    }
}
```

The `T` in `foo` is a brand new generic parameter, different from the `T` in `MyType`. They just so happens to have the same name.

Note that when you declare a generic method, it's the *caller* that decides what the generic type is, not the generic method. What `foo` is trying to say here is "I want the `T` in `foo` to be the same type as the `T` in `MyType`", but it can't say that about its own generic parameters!

One way to fix it is to make `SecondProtocol` have an associated type:

```
protocol SecondProtocol {
    // name this properly!
    associatedtype SomeType: FirstProtocol
    func foo(argument: SomeType)
}

class MyType<T: FirstProtocol>: SecondProtocol {
    typealias SomeType = T // here is where it says "I want 'SomeType' to be the same type as 'T'!"
    var value: T? = nil
    func foo(argument: T) {
        value = argument
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, that works in the simple example I gave you, the problem is then I can only use as SecondProtocol generic constraint, which breaks how other people are using it in the project I'm working on. I really want to do something like foo<T1>(argument: T1) where T1 == T, but the compiler then complains "Same-type requirement makes generic parameters 'T1' and 'T' equivalent", but that's what I want.

Comment: Since what I'm trying to do is only for unit testing I found a slightly hacky solution involving casting.

Answer (score 0):

> it will not let me assign argument to value even though value and argument should be the same type, the compiler complains as if they are different types.

think about this case:

class A: FirstProtocol {
}

class B: FirstProtocol {
}

class A and B is the acceptable generic type for func foo(argument: T){}, but can you assign an instance of class A to class B?

```
class MyType<T: FirstProtocol>: SecondProtocol
```

remove ": FirstProtocol"should work, or use a base class to replace FirstProtocol